# addItemViewController:didFinishEditingItem does not pass edited item to main view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Have added a method and protocol to pass the addItemViewController:didFinishEditingItem method to the main view controller (ChecklistsViewController) after completing a text edit. (The edit command and segue are invoked by pressing a disclosure detail button on the Checklists main page.)

Problem is that after completing the edit and pressing the "Done" button, no completed text edit gets passed back to the original Checklists page, which means that the original edit was was not passed over. I have had no compiling warning messages.

Can you tell me what's wrong and why no completed edit is getting passed back to Checklists? Thanks in advance.

AddItemViewController.h

## import

```
@class AddItemViewController;
@class ChecklistItem;

@protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel:(AddItemViewController *)controller;

- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item;

- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishEditingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item;



@end

@interface AddItemViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ChecklistItem *itemToEdit;

- (IBAction)cancel;
- (IBAction)done;

@end
```

AddItemViewController.m

```
#import "AddItemViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistItem.h"

@interface AddItemViewController ()

@end


@implementation AddItemViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(self.itemToEdit != nil) {
        self.title = @"Edit Item";
        self.textField.text = self.itemToEdit.text;
        self.doneBarButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (IBAction)cancel
{
    [self.delegate addItemViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

- (IBAction)done
{
    if(self.itemToEdit == nil) {
    ChecklistItem *item = [[ChecklistItem alloc] init];
    item.text = self.textField.text;
    item.checked = NO;

    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishAddingItem:item];
    } else {
    self.itemToEdit.text = self.textField.text;
    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEditingItem:self.itemToEdit];
    }
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setTextField:nil];
    [self setDoneBarButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newText = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    self.doneBarButton.enabled = ([newText length] > 0);

    return YES;
}
@end
```

ChecklistsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddItemViewController.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController : UITableViewController <AddItemViewControllerDelegate>



@end
```

ChecklistsViewController.m

```
#import "ChecklistsViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistItem.h"

@interface ChecklistsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChecklistsViewController {
    NSMutableArray *items;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

    ChecklistItem *item;

    item = [[ChecklistItem alloc]init];
    item.text = @"Walk the dog";
    item.checked = NO;
    [items addObject:item];

    item = [[ChecklistItem alloc]init];
    item.text = @"Brush my teeth";
    item.checked = YES;
    [items addObject:item];

    item = [[ChecklistItem alloc]init];
    item.text = @"Learn iOS development";
    item.checked = YES;
    [items addObject:item];

    item = [[ChecklistItem alloc]init];
    item.text = @"Soccer practice";
    item.checked = NO;
    [items addObject:item];

    item = [[ChecklistItem alloc]init];
    item.text = @"Eat ice cream";
    item.checked = YES;
    [items addObject:item];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [items count];
}

- (void)configureCheckmarkForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withChecklistItem:(ChecklistItem *)item
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    if(item.checked) {
        label.text =@"√";
    } else {
        label.text = @"";
    }

}

- (void)configureTextForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withChecklistItem:(ChecklistItem *)item
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    label.text = item.text;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];

    ChecklistItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self configureTextForCell:cell withChecklistItem:item];
    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withChecklistItem:item];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ChecklistItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditItem" sender:item];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    ChecklistItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [item toggleChecked];


    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withChecklistItem:item];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (void)addItemViewControllerDidCancel:(AddItemViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item
{
    int newRowIndex = [items count];
    [items addObject:item];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishEditingItem:(ChecklistItem *)item
{
    int index = [items indexOfObject:item];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withChecklistItem:item];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddItem"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddItemViewController *controller = (AddItemViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditItem"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddItemViewController *controller = (AddItemViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.itemToEdit = sender;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Your question is too long & I'm feeling sleepy –_

Comment: you  mean all the AddItemViewControllerDelegate methods are not getting fired in checkListViewController??

Comment: When I click on the disclosure detail button it passes to the AddItemViewController for editing fine. But when I edit and click Done, none of the added content gets passed back to the ChecklistsViewController and gets displayed as it originally was; it stays the same without change. So I am thinking it's something wrong with the new method which was added and how it handles delegation.